# What options are there for old soulbound gear in GW2?

Tags: guild-wars-2

My warrior recently replaced his Exotic amulet with an Ascended amulet.

I was wondering what are my options when it comes to old soulbound gear. Naturally, it can't be used on any of the other characters or sold in the Trading Post because it is soulbound.

If it was a Rare gear, I would have just salvaged it for a chance to get Ectoplasm but it seem like a huge waste to salvage my old Exotic gear that I've replace with a Ascended gear.

Are there any other options?

Answer (score 4):

You can do a nice gamble by putting it in the Mystic Forge in order to try and get a precursor weapon:

Have look here under the head "Acquisition":
http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Precursor_weapon

> Combining four rare or exotic pieces of equipment with an average
>   level of 75 or higher, e.g. one L60 weapon + three L80 weapons or
>   three L75 pieces of armor and a L75 weapon

Comment: Your odds of getting a precursor from your old gear are so small I doubt it's ever happened to anyone.

Comment: I meant "nice gamble" as mildly sarcastic. It is theoretically possible to get a precursor though and therefore an alternative to salvage. I personally only salvaged my old stuff.

Answer (score 3):

Your options are:

1. Sell it the a merchant
2. [Salvage](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Salvage) it
3. Throw it into the [Mystic Forge](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Mystic_forge) with 3 similar items

But note that you won't be able to sell or salvage any gear that was acquired from a [karma merchant](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Karma_merchant) or the helms that are rewarded for dungeons' story mode. Salvaging is often your best option for level 68+ rare or exotic gear, for the chance to obtain [ecto](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Glob_of_Ectoplasm), otherwise selling to a merchant is likely your most profitable option.

Comment: Can you transmute soul-bound gear between characters? For example if I had a sword bound to Toon1, could Toon2 use it's skin with a different item?

Comment: There's a trick where you can transmute to a white or blue rarity item and move it through the bank to allow another character to use it, but I don't know if that still works. You can find more details at http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Talk:Transmutation#Transmuting_Soulbound_items

Comment: @DavidYell You can't take anything out of the bank that is soulbound to another character. So that won't work.

Comment: @Jay It does work because white items are not soul-bound. That's the trick.

Comment: @Jay is correct, confirmed as 'Myth Busted' http://imgur.com/hMNl23S

Comment: @DavidYell It looks like your error there is "Stat item cannot use that upgrade" which sounds like it's because you're trying to put an upgrade on a weapon with no upgrade slot.

Comment: I had not noticed that! D'oh